# Android app, check if EditText with INTEGER is empty or not

Tags: java, android

I have a problem trying to check if a EditText is empty or not. I have found a lot of solutions but all of them reffer to a string variable.
I wanna check if a value that is Integer between 0 and 10 is empty or not.

Here is my code:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(instances.getText().toString());;
if (value > 10)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (value < 0)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (value >= 0 && value <= 10) {
    schimba(v);
}
```

If I enter a number > 10 I get the toast, same if I enter a negative number.The function work great when I enter the number between 0 and 10 but if I let empty I get an error and I need to create the condition but I can't find something to integer.

Any help would be great, thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to check if the edittext is empty or not????

Comment: (string)value == ""; ?

Comment: I wanna check if he is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about doing:

```
 if (instances.getText().toString().lenght() > 0)
{
 int value = Integer.parseInt(instances.getText().toString());;
        if(value > 10)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            if(value<0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                if(value >= 0 && value <=10)
                {
                    schimba(v);
                }
}
else
{
  // HANDLE EMPTY VALUE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matches()` method to check that your `EditText` is empty or not.

```
String stringValue = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (!stringValue.matches("")) {

    int value = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
    if(value > 10)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else if(value<0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else if(value >= 0 && value <=10) {
        schimba(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String _data = instances.getText().toString().lenght()    
   if (_data  > 0){
     int value = Integer.parseInt(_data );;
       if(value > 10)
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       else if(value<0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(value >= 0 && value <=10)
            {
                schimba(v);
            }
}else{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg you want to display!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified sample code

```
int value = instances.getText().toString()!=null && !instances.getText().toString().equals("") ? Integer.parseInt(instances.getText().toString()) : -1;
if (value < 0 || value > 10){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value between 0 and 10!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    schimba(v);
}
```